# Compute $ \int_{\mathbb R} |\sin x| e^{-(x-a)^2 / b^2} dx $

Tags: calculus, probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

For $a, b > 0$, I want to compute $$\int_{\mathbb R} |\sin x| e^{-(x-a)^2 / b^2} dx.$$

What I have tried:

Since $\int_{\mathbb R} |\sin x| e^{-(x-a)^2 / b^2} dx= \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} \int_{0}^{\pi} (\sin x) e^{-(x-a-k\pi)^2 / b^2} dx$, I tried calculating $\int_{0}^{\pi}(\sin x) e^{-(x-a)^2 / b^2} dx$, but I cannot proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

Ps. Even a good bound is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will compute $\int_{\mathbb R} |\sin x| g(x) dx$ instead where $g$ is the Gaussian density with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
By the Poisson summation formula, it is equal to $$\frac{4}{\pi} \Big(1-2 \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{e^{-2\sigma^2 k^2}}{4k^2 -1 }\cos (2k\mu)\Big).$$

This follows from the following consideration.
Notice $\int_{0}^{\pi} (\sin x) e^{-(x-\mu-k\pi)^2 / 2\sigma^2}/\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2} dx= (f \ast g)(\mu+k\pi)$ where $f(x)= 1_{[0,\pi]}(x) \sin x$ and $\ast$ is the convolution. We want to calculate $\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} (f\ast g) (\mu+k\pi)$. By the Poisson summation formula, it is equal to $$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} \hat f(2k)\hat g(2k)e^{i2k \mu}.$$ It is easy to check that $\hat f(2k)= \frac{2}{1-4k^2}$ and $\hat g(2k)= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{2\sigma^2 k^2 }$, so we are done by noticing that our result must be a real number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is enough.
$$ \begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb R} |\sin x| e^{-(x-a)^2 / b^2} dx & \le \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-(x-a)^2 / b^2} dx \\ [c := \frac{b}{\sqrt{2}} ] \qquad & = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{\frac{-(x-a)^2}{2c^2}} dx\\ & =  \sqrt{2\pi c^2} \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi c^2}} e^{\frac{-(x-a)^2}{2c^2}} dx  \\ & = \sqrt{2\pi c^2}
\end{split}$$

Where the last equalty is valid since  $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi c^2}} e^{\frac{-(x-a)^2}{2c^2}} dx = 1$ since the inner function is the density function of a normal distribution with mean $a$ and variance $c^2$

Comment: Thanks for your help Gabrielek! But I actually wanted a bound that can reflect `a` as well. Intuitively, if `a = n\pi ` for some `n`, the normal distribution is peaked at the location where `|sin x| = 0` so we can expect the integral to be small. Likewise, when `a = (2n+1)\pi / 2 ` for some `n`, the integral would be larger. I wanted the bound to reflect such changes. But still, thanks for taking your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how helpful this is but perhaps you can use the Fourier Series of $|\sin(x)|$?
$$|\sin(x)|=\frac{2}{\pi}\left(1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\pi n)+1}{1-n^2} \cos(nx) \right)$$